# QGIS 3.4.2 on Windows: pyqgis 3 rule-visibility depending on scale

Tags: pyqgis-3, visibility

I have a plugin for QGIS 2.18. In QGIS 2.18 it was possible, to toggle the visibility of each of the 7 "sublayers" (see below) by python-code:

```
    symbol = QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple({'name': 'circle'}) # Markersymbol benennen; z.B.: [ square, diamond, pentagon, triangle, circle, cross2, x ].
    renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol) # Kreieren eines neuen Regel-basierten Renderers.
    root_rule = renderer.rootRule() # Holen der "root" Regel.
    for label, expression, color, groesse, maszstab in Statusregeln:
        rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone() # Kopie der default-rule erzeugen.
        rule.setLabel(label)
        rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
        rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color))
        rule.symbol().setSize(groesse)
        rule.setScaleMinDenom(1)
        rule.setScaleMaxDenom(int(maszstab))
        root_rule.appendChild(rule) # Anhängen der rule an die Liste.
    root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
    layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

In QGIS 3 the methods "setScaleMinDenom" and "setScaleMaxDenom" don't work anymore.

Is there a replacement in QGIS3?

If not yet existing, is it planned?

### [image]

I used 
*rule.setMaximumScale(int(maszstab))*
I am using QGIS 3.4.2 for Windows 7, 64-bit. Maybe the QGIS-version is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The methods you mentioned have been removed for QGIS 3 as described in the [Backwards Incompatible Changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) document:

> QgsRuleBasedRenderer.Rule scaleMinDenom(), scaleMaxDenom(), setScaleMaxDenom() and setScaleMinDenom() were removed. Use minimumScale(), maximumScale(), setMinimumScale() and setMaximumScale() instead.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I used setMinimumScale() and setMaximumScale(), but they are working only for the whole layer, not espacially for the "sublayers". This was possible in QGIS 2.

Comment: @uwe2812 - Seems to work for me (tested on QGIS 3.8.1 for Windows 7 64-bit). Did you set it using `rule.setMaximumScale(int(maszstab))`?